# could not access file "pg_wait_sampling": No such file or directory postgresql

Tags: postgresql

after I use the following command then I cannot relogin postgresql
`alter system set shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_wait_sampling';`

exit trying login again. Then error happens. The following is error code:

```
2022-03-15 11:35:30.726 IST [975] FATAL:  could not access file "pg_wait_sampling": No such file or directory
2022-03-15 11:35:30.727 IST [975] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

postgresql version: 14.2. system: wsl ubuntu.
in conf file /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf":

```
#shared_preload_libraries='' #(change requires restart)
```

Comment: The problem is that you didn't install the software, so that the extension is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PostgreSQL document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altersystem.html) `alter` command store in **postgresql.auto.conf** file.

You have to change this file and remove **pg_wait_sampling** form this file